# Borel Sets and complements

Tags: probability

This is a trivial question. But won't both sides of the equation be equal to zero if both events are independent? $$ P(A)P(B) - P(A\cap B) = P(A^c\cap B) - P(A^c)P(B)$$

And if it, how then do we show that the LHS is equivalent to the RHS? Does it suffice to say that $$P(A\cap B^c) \le 1-P(A\cap B)$$

Comment: Your are right that if A,B are independent then both sides are 0. But the equation holds for all A,B.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, they will.
2. $P(B\setminus A)-P(X\setminus A)P(B)=P(B)-P(B\cap A)-(1-P(A))P(B)=\\=P(A)P(B)-P(B\cap A)$
3. No, it doesn't.

Comment: how then do we prove $$P(A\cap B^c) \le 1-P(A\cap B)$$

Comment: Prove that $P(A^c\cap B)+P(A\cap B)=P(B). $

Comment: @Lady Ah, so it was "prove the inequality from the identity" rather than "prove the identity from the inequality". Truth to be told, that inequality is an immediate consequence of some tools I've used in point (2). Since they are very basilar, the exercise for you is to spot which ones and why.

Answer (score 0):

The equation is equivalent to $$P(A^c)P(B)+P(A)P(B)=P(A\cap B)+P(A^c\cap B).$$ The LHS of this is $(P(A^c)+P(A))P(B)=(1)P(B)=P(B).$

I will leave it to you to confirm that the RHS, $P(A\cap B)+P(A^c\cap B)$ is also equal to $P(B).$